# Safari: mix-blend-mode luminosity not working correctly

Tags: css, transform, mix-blend-mode

I have a `mix-blend-mode` for one of my images that works perfectly on firefox and chrome, but not on safari. The overlay is on a CSS slider I have and I found `transform` messes up the `mix-blend-mode` property. How do I avoid having the transform interfere with the css styling.

I am using the **[Swiper Slider](https://idangero.us/swiper/)**

Below I placed my code and exactly how it should look. The final result should look like this:

[image]

```css
section {
  position: relative;
  will-change: opacity;
}

section::after {
  background-color: #3b5873;
  border: 33.325px solid #c4ae7e;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: calc(100% - 66.65px);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 66.65px);
}

.container {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  mix-blend-mode: luminosity;
  z-index: 9;
}

.image-bg {
  background-size: cover;
  padding-top: 59.08%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="image-bg" style="background-image:url('http://dev-thepaxton.pantheonsite.io/wp-content/themes/paxton-theme/dist/images/home/gallery_0.jpg')"></div>
   </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I have the exact same result on both my FF 68 and Safari 12.1.1

Comment: Yes same, I'm just saying thats the idea I want. With the swiper slider it somehow breaks. @Kaiido

Comment: Well give us this. We can't help fix something that's not broken...

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `mix-blend-mode` is not supported for Safari/WebKit SVG elements:

https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_mix-blend-mode_svg